# professional or boring?

Tags: portfolio

I really don't know if this is allowed here, but I am going to give this a shot.

Here is my web development [portfolio](http://philipimperato.com). I am not a designer, but I thought it was pretty good looking. I want to know if this design is boring and probably shouldn't be shown to prospect employers or is it "enough" for a web developer?

Any critics/advice/suggestions?

Again, first post, not sure what is allowed here.

Comment: StackExchange's format is questions that have answers that tend to have consensus. "How does this look?" doesn't quite fit the formula, unfortunately. As for your question: Don't mistake 'pragmatic' for 'boring'. Does your web site achieve what you intended it to do in a way that isn't ugly? If so, it's good.

Comment: Da01 according to our Meta and Faq at this point in time we do allow critiques.

Comment: then disregard my previous comment!

Comment: Like the minimalism.. but if your'e a web developer you should probably fix the code... you know... add closing body and html tags.

Comment: You need to fix the glaring spelling mistake in your masthead graphic, look at the capitalisation of your major and completely rethink your third sentence.

Comment: consider putting in a dynamic left margin or centering. On my large screen, I have 2/3 of the window as blank white space. White space can be luxurious, but the placement of your content make it seem off balance instead: like a see-saw with only one person. Also: consider making and displaying your own resume, rather than linking off site to an stackexchange. All you are doing is showing you can fill in forms on a web site and then link it.

Comment: @horatio But I really think that the "top 20%" CSS would be a fantastic real world way of showing employees I know the business.

Comment: @e100 Wow, didn't even notice that, thank you. I removed the last sentence completely as I don't think it's needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am not a designer, but I thought it was pretty good looking.

Honestly I felt i am viewing a site might be its is designed for any ipad or big mobile phone not for my desktop at all.

> this design is boring and probably shouldn't be shown to prospect employers

its is good looking coz there is nothing much,like on what basis you can decide that it's looking good there is always much of content place and all.but we have nothing so this is small sweet and meaning full at one point and another point a web developer  probably will show that he knows so many things about design and coding  and all the stuff he worked on so this is your platform to show off your skills and your work.

so i would suggest you to pick some color some attractive colors,backgrounds and everything which simply represent you as a web developer ..

I consider my self as a dumb in this knowledge hub, there are so many talented designer on this site, so I don't have any critics, I have suggestions, you should check.

1. As scott mentioned your code does not have closing tags which is really bad you should avoid such mistakes.
2. I have seen your CSS which i felt it goes only for font family and font property. so CSS is not upto that only, mostly it is used to align the things / blocks in a manner. You can do pretty well if you just look concentrated.
3. I would suggest you to check some portfolio websites for your inspirations after all you want to show this to employers it should be attractive but take my words `too much of anything will ruin everything` so be sober, be simple just look for inspiration and work with your mind's creativity

---

Some resources for your inspiration.

- [Single page webdesign](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/inspiration/single-page-website-designs/)
- [One page love](http://onepagelove.com/)

Hope you'll meet your goals positively..

Comment: Thank you so very much, for the resources and critiques! I have a love/hate relationship with my portfolio if I attempt at some design. I will try and spice it up some!

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing on your portfolio and and the bottom at least in Safari is touching the bottom of my browser. Could really use a buffer area at the bottom so that I can scroll down to make your contact info more towards the middle of my screen. Otherwise its very minimal but has good use of typography in my opinion. Hard to say if its enough without a portfolio. If your portfolio is strong it will speak for itself, if your portfolio is weak then you might need more on your personal site to show you know what you're doing.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that! Thank you for reminding me!

Answer (score 0):

I like it for a start. The typography is interesting and the minimalist feel is inviting. Now put some actual, you know, stuff in it, and we can give you more of an answer.